# How to stretch flexbox to fill the entire container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a container with two flexboxes that needs to be stretched so that the height of both flexboxes fill the entire containere. In the left flexbox I have a image that must fill the entire left flexbox. I have troubles in getting both of the flexboxes to fill the entire container height.

html code

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="mainContainerAboutUs">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg" id = "aboutUsLeft">
            <img src = {% static 'media/cover.jpg' %} alt = 'About us' id = "aboutUsLeftImage">
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-lg" id = "aboutUsRight">
                <img src={% static 'media/HIDDEN DIMSUM logo final.png' %} alt="logo" id = "aboutUsLogo">
                <h1 id = "aboutUsRightHeader">We are dimsum!</h1>
                <hr class = "cardDeckHorisontalLine">
                <h3>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe iure a quia ab, animi magni repellendus voluptatem quo magnam recusandae id sit, nam enim illum voluptatibus error possimus ratione quisquam.
                </h3>           
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
/*About us section */
#mainContainerAboutUs {
    align-items: stretch;
    display: flex;
} 

#aboutUsLeft {
    padding: 0px;
    border: 5px solid grey;
}

#aboutUsLeftImage {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#aboutUsRight {
    justify-content: center;
    border: 5px solid grey;
}

#aboutUsLogo {
    width: 10%;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
}

#aboutUsRightHeader {text-align: center;}
```

I have read from google search that align-items:stretch should do the job, but in this case it doesn't work. Basically what I want to achieve is indicated by the arrow on the image below.
[image]

Comment: What is the size of the images?

Comment: It is 2732 × 2000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the issue with the empty white space on top of the container is realted to some 
 tags inserted in the previous html section. Also I found that as soon as I use `border: 5px red solid` in css, I can see the container box as well as the flex boxes. It made the debugging much easier for me.

I have revised the code as below, but I still have one issue. Upon narrowing the browser window width, the image dissapeared.

html

```
<div class="container-fluid" id = "aboutUsContainer">
    <div class="row" id="firstRow">
        <img src = {% static 'media/cover.jpg' %} class="col-lg" alt = 'About us' id = "aboutUsLeftImage">

        <div class="col-lg" id="right"> 
            <img src={% static 'media/HIDDEN DIMSUM logo final.png' %} alt="logo" id = "aboutUsLogo">
                <h1 id = "aboutUsRightHeader">We are dimsum!</h1>
                <hr class = "cardDeckHorisontalLine">
                <h3>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe iure a quia ab, animi magni repellendus voluptatem quo magnam recusandae id sit, nam enim illum voluptatibus error possimus ratione quisquam.
                </h3>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and css

```
.row {
    display: flex;
}

#aboutUsLeftImage {
  object-fit: cover;
  flex: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 500px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#aboutUsLogo {
    width: 10%;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
}

#aboutUsRightHeader {text-align: center;}
```

I did removed the flexbox div on my left image, as I read somewhere that the img tag alone served as a flexbox? if that is correct, how come that the image dissapeared upon browser window narrowing?

Comment: what is even more strange is if I add border: 5px solid red; css tag to #aboutUsLeftImage, I got the behavior I wanted, but this is not a solution I can live with as I don't want the border around this flexbox.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing `align-items: stretch` on wrong element, you need to do it on `row` which contains the flex items, your css should be:

```
#mainContainerAboutUs .row {
    align-items: stretch;
}
```

**OR**

If you're using Bootstrap 4 edit your html to:

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="mainContainerAboutUs">
    <div class="row align-items-stretch">
        <div class="col-lg" id = "aboutUsLeft">
            <img src = {% static 'media/cover.jpg' %} alt = 'About us' id = "aboutUsLeftImage">
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-lg" id = "aboutUsRight">
                <img src={% static 'media/HIDDEN DIMSUM logo final.png' %} alt="logo" id = "aboutUsLogo">
                <h1 id = "aboutUsRightHeader">We are dimsum!</h1>
                <hr class = "cardDeckHorisontalLine">
                <h3>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe iure a quia ab, animi magni repellendus voluptatem quo magnam recusandae id sit, nam enim illum voluptatibus error possimus ratione quisquam.
                </h3>           
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: None of the above solutions solved the problem. I attached a picture in my post to show clearly what I want to achieve. Basically I need both of the flexboxes to fill the entire container upper part.